# Custom transaction level in Delphi DBX firebird

Tags: delphi, transactions, firebird, delphi-xe

I am looking for a way to specify a custom transaction level in Delphi's DBX using the firebird driver. I am using Delphi XE.

In the Parameter editor of the TSQLConnection component I can set various TransIsolation values and I'm using the default of `ReadCommited`. The property `WaitOnLocks` is set to `True`.
I expect this uses the following firebird transaction configuration but I'm not sure:

`READ WRITE + WAIT + SNAPSHOT` (see http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-set-trans.html)

I would like to use `LOCK TIMEOUT [seconds]` instead of `WAIT`. But I can't find how or where to specify this. I've looked in the DBX source files and there is some code for custom transaction levels (search for `xilCUSTOM`) but it seems unfinished/unused.

The reason for this is that we sometimes experience a deadlock in our multi-user datasnap application and I think it's because one transaction is waiting on another (possibly dead) transaction. We would rather have the transaction break after a couple of seconds than have the whole client hangup indefinitely.

Comment: Following documentation `In addition, TSQLConnection lets you specify database-specific custom isolation levels. Custom isolation levels are defined by the dbExpress driver. See your driver documentation for details.`

Comment: Is it in your consideration to buy a documented interbase driver? Or use more native salution like IBDAC or IB Objects (+performance + compatibility +support)?

Comment: Apart from you issues with the wait timeout, absolutely make sure you understand the deadlock conditions occurring in your application. This smells of a flawed Transaction logic, very long running transactions, unsafe use of triggers etc. which will only get worse over time, Timeout or not.